# How can I improve my vert and park skateboarding skills?

Tags: technique, training, skateboarding

I consider myself very much a Street and Old School skateboarder but I would like to learn how to better myself in parks and on vertical ramps.

As I'm starting to take part in tournaments, what skills do I need to work on (for example balance and pumping to gain speed)?

Most of all, I want to know the ways in which I can improve my slides/grinds, stalls and airs in parks and verts. Also I would like to know when would be the best time to Pump on the ramps and pipes to gain the most speed?

Any ideas?

To clear up any confusion, by vert I mean pipes like quarter and half pipes that have a ramp to vertical and over vert refers to ramps that bend backwards to almost make you go upside down. ramps such as full pipes.

Comment: Vert as in vertical?

Comment: as in vertical ramps yes and often over vert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this:
- certainly look for some of the most popular spots around your area such as short stairs or good lines, but do them over and over. It may be tedious at first but getting that muscle memory is important for reaching longer or more intense lines

- make sure your board is outfitted the right way. Make sure you have smooth bearings and good trucks, because those will give you the speed you want for the ollies and on the vert ramp.
- gain a lot of leg and upper body strength. This is important for the jumps and flips you will be doing on the vert ramps too. 
  hope this helps! Lemme know if you have need of any other tips
  -Paul

Comment: I was wondering on the pump technique when would be best to shift my weight forward?